# Execute bash command from container (flatpak) in the main OS

Tags: linux, container, flatpak

Here's my problem. I am running flatpak steam and I want to interact with libratbag for managing my mouse poll rate. Running my custom command from the game launch options won't work, as everything is run in the flatpak container.

I thought of creating a systems service that runs whatever is us sent in a pipe that I create in my local home folder. A little hacky but should work. Any other suggestion or anything I am overlooking?